# Same command but different result, odd behavior between cmd and python subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, rtsp, video-recording

Hello and thanks everyone, I am having a very strange phenomenon and I hope you can help me solve it, I run a command through the cmd to save video coming from a camera to a local file in my  computer,the command is :

**ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://root:senswim2018@10.0.0.101/axis-media/media.amp" -c copy foo.mp4**

when I run the command through the cmd it works fine (recorded a video longer than 12 hours), but when I run it as a command "Using the subprocess in Python, it only records around 5:30 minutes

**cmd = ["ffmpeg","-rtsp_transport","tcp", "-i", "rtsp://root:senswim2018@10.0.0.101/axis-media/media.amp" ,"-c", "copy","foo.mp4"]**

**process = subprocess.Popen(cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)**

**time.sleep(600000)**

**process.terminate()**

This matter is very confusing and unclear to me, I would be very happy if you could give some insight thanks.

Comment: Have you tried subprocess.run(cmd, timout=600000)?

Comment: Does the command stop after 5:30 minutes or is it still running, just not recording?

Comment: yes i tried to use timeout and this is still not working , good question i will check if it stop to record or take only the last 5:30 minutes

Comment: How are you handling ffmpeg's stderr?